Is there a way to restrict only union type in the argument?
I am trying to restrict an argument of a function to be only union type.
For example:
type UnionType = readonly string[];

const getSelector = <T extends UnionType>(arg: T)=>{
  return (validType: T[number])=>{
    return 'data is '+(!arg.includes(validType) ? "NOT " : '') + "included";
  }
}

const myFunc = getSelector(["opt1", "opt2", "opt3"] as const); // <== should be fine!
myFunc("opt1"); // auto complete is working!

const myFunc2 = getSelector(["optA", "optB", "optC"]);
myFunc2("optA"); // auto complete is NOT working! since the given options are not const.
// how can I RESTRICT the options as const type?


As you see above example, I tried to make the extended type with readonly keyword. I also tried Readonly<string[]>. Multiple trials that might not make sense so not sharing here, but I wonder if there is even a way that there is even a way to make it possible.

Are you really trying to restrict the type argument? Like, if you write const x: string[] = ["a", "b", c"], you would like to prohibit getSelector(x)? Or do you just want it so that getSelector(["a", "b", "c"]) will infer a union?  If all you care about is inference, the other answers here give possibilities. If you really want to reject calls, then something like this approach would work. What are you trying to accomplish?

this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

I love this solution either! but cannot understand how it works. const getSelector = <T extends string>(arg: readonly T[] & (string extends T ? never : unknown)) => {     return (validType: T) => {         return 'data is ' + (!arg.includes(validType) ? "NOT " : '') + "included";     } } from here, & (string extends T ? never : unknown) part is hard to understand..

Well, I'd write up an explanation of it but you already accepted the other answer. I'm not inclined to spend a lot of effort on that.

This is exactly the use-case for which const type parameters were released in typescript 5.
Simply add const to the type and auto complete should start working:
type UnionType = readonly string[];

const getSelector = <const T extends UnionType>(arg: T)=>{
  return (validType: T[number])=>{
    return 'data is '+(!arg.includes(validType) ? "NOT " : '') + "included";
  }
}

const myFunc = getSelector(["opt1", "opt2", "opt3"] as const); // <== should be fine!
myFunc("opt1"); // auto complete is working!

const myFunc2 = getSelector(["optA", "optB", "optC"]);
myFunc2("optA"); // <== should also be fine!
// @ts-expect-error: Remove this line to see the error
myFunc2("optD"); // <== ERROR!

^^ Looks like the syntax throws off SO's highlighter ^^
Playground

this one is so elegant solution! I like it! I like the other answer from Alexander Nenashev either, but this answer did not even change the type. I will choose this one!

Just level up the generic type:
Playground
const getSelector = <T extends string>(arg: T[])=>{
  return (validType: T) =>{
    return 'data is '+(!arg.includes(validType) ? "NOT " : '') + "included";
  }
}

const myFunc = getSelector(['opt1', "opt2", "opt3"] as const); // <== should be fine!
myFunc('opt1'); // auto complete is working!

const myFunc2 = getSelector(["optA", "optB", "optC"]);
myFunc2('optA'); // auto complete is NOT working! since the given options are not const.
// how can I RESTRICT the options as const type?


What difference does this make?

@Bergi it converts const myFunc2: (validType: string) => string to const myFunc2: (validType: "optA" | "optB" | "optC") => string

Yes, but why does it do that? How is type inference affected by choosing the different generic?

@Bergi since T extends string refers to a specific subset type of the string but T еxtends string[] doesn't?

No, T could just as well refer to string with T extends string. So why wouldn't T refer to a specific array subset type in T extends readonly string[]?

@Bergi read the other answer and follow the link where it's explained. i'm more about usage then pointing to a spec

I had hoped you could put an explanation (or at least a link to it) in your answer. The other answer uses const T, it doesn't explain any difference between T and T[]

An explanation would be nice. It would presumably be a result of the rules as implemented in ms/TS#10676

I liked this answer as well! just chose the other one since it did not even change the type to the other. But this is a really good solution either!
